# Is there a way to calculate time differences in MySQL using one select

Tags: mysql

I have a table containing the following:

```
name    type
id    : INT
date1 : DATETIME
date2 : DATETIME
```

And I need to calculate the difference between date2 and date1.

This is possible using the [TIMEDIFF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff) function in MySQL.

However, is there a way to get the result of TIMEDIFF(date2,date1) using one select, and not using 2 helper selects:

```
select TIMEDIFF( (select date2 from example_table where id=1) , (select date1 from example_table where id=1) );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select TIMEDIFF( date2 ,date1) from example_table where id=1;
```