# Calculating time differences in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to calculate time differences in MySQL using one select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586773/is-there-a-way-to-calculate-time-differences-in-mysql-using-one-select)

I have this kind of table in my db:

```
last_login_time     last_logout_time
2011-07-11 17:29:28 2011-07-11 16:11:58
2011-07-11 17:29:28 2011-07-11 16:14:35
2011-07-11 17:29:28 2011-07-11 16:40:18
2011-07-11 17:29:28 0000-00-00 00:00:00
2011-07-11 17:29:28 2011-07-11 16:47:26
2011-07-11 17:29:28 2011-07-11 16:49:13
2011-07-11 17:29:28 2011-07-11 16:53:21
2011-07-11 17:29:28 2011-07-11 17:35:59
```

I want to calculate in another column the duration of the session (i.e. last_logout_time - last_login_time)
In another column I want so sum up all the duartions.

I'm using MySQL and PHP.

Thanks!

Comment: The question is how do I measure the duration between each login and logout and then sum it up? What is the query?

Comment: The downvoting is a bit harsh -  it's perfectly obvious what the OP wants. @Sharon see [Date and time functions in mySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: It "does not show any research effort", which is a listed reason to down-vote something.  Not saying you should downvote it, but... certainly acceptable to imo.  It seems if you're using MySQL and PHP, and have set this up so far to keep track of times..etc, you're knowledgeable enough to at least ATTEMPT something via a SELECT, PHP loop to add to a variable holding the times...etc - at least try something, then post this.  Otherwise, you should narrow your question down to "determine the difference between two times with PHP".  The question as it stands appears more like a "give me code".

Comment: Was solved by this query:

    UPDATE registration set today_session_time=TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF('".$logout."','" .$login. "')) where nickname=".$_SESSION['nickname'];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF(last_logout_time, last_login_time) AS last_duration FROM...
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
select sum( last_logout_time-last_login_time )
```

Comment: This will fail on that null column showing up as 0000-00-00...

Comment: @Marc - fair enough - i didnt even see that in there...  you should wrap that part in a case statement to get current date/time, or exclude that record in the where clause...

Comment: I also want to store in another column the duration for each session (last_logout_time-last_login_time)

Comment: @Sharon: Storing derived data is usually not a good idea. Doing a simple subtraction of the two fields is a "cheap" operation and can be done in any other queries that require the duration value.

Comment: @Marc: Thanks for the advice, but I also need to store that info.

Comment: Why? It's a waste of space. I'd agree with storing derived data if it's the result of a complicated query that's "expensive" to run. But you're just doing a simple subtraction which is essentially zero cost.

Comment: Because the users login each day once only and I want to see which one was logged in the most little amount of time.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Randy's answer:

`SELECT SUM(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(last_logout_time)-UNIX_TIMESTAMP(last_login_time))`

This will (theoretically) get you the total seconds. Divide by 60 for minutes, etcetcetc.

Comment: MySQL has a `TIMEDIFF()` function too.